# Error importing a file: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I know there are a lot of questions asking the same I'm now asking, but I've tried most of their answers and they doesn't fix my problem.
I have a file named `fileA.py` where I need to call and import `fileB.py`. Until now i was doing this:

```
# in fileA.py
import fileB.py
```

And it was working. But suddenly now it does not. It gives me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fileB'
```

They are on the same folder at the same level.
I've tried all of these solutiones:

```
import folder.fileB
from . import fileB
import fileB.py
```

And still same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like `sys.path` may have changed.  Ensure the parent directory of both modules is in `sys.path` and give it another try.  If not, please update the question with the directory structure and the output of sys path.

Comment: when you import `fileB`, you should just do `import fileB`. other than that, you need to put all script in the same directory and add `__init__.py` in the same directory. If all of these do not work for you, try `runpy` as linked here: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use absolute imports. Starting from the root, assume you have a folder called `folder` which holds your modules, you would import it like so:

```py
from folder import fileB
```

If `folder` is not the root of the code, then start from the root source folder:

```py
from root_source_folder.some_package.folder import fileB
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
import fileB
```

or

```
from fileB import *
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `present working directory` in terminal while executing your code is same as that of `fileA.py`.